# Application exited unexpectedly with no error when trying to call function from another file - PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

So i have an app where i built using tkinter and now i'm trying to change the UI but using PyQt5 and im stucked on a weird problem. (For me at least)

Basically, its a login button, when clicked, calls the logincheck function where it tries to validate the username and password given from sql database but the function is on another file

main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import sys,sql

class Ui_login(object):
    def setupUi(self, login):
        #some codes generated by PyQt
        self.button_login = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_login.setObjectName("button_login")
        self.button_login.clicked.connect(self.logincheck)
        #more PyQt generated codes here

    def logincheck(self, event):
        _result = sql.logincheck(self.entry_user.text().lower(), self.entry_pass.text(),"main")
        _userlvl = 0
        if type(_result) != bool:
            _userlvl = _result[2]
            _result = _result[0]
        print(_result)
        if _result == True:
            self.logindestroy(_userlvl)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Banana: Error","Invalid login credential")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_login()
    ui.setupUi(login)
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

sql.py:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import mysql.connector as mysql

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('cfg.ini')

def connect():
    global aMysql,mydb
    mydb = mysql.connect(
        host=config.get("db","host"),
        user=config.get("db","user"),
        password=config.get("db","password"),
        database=config.get("db","database")
    )
    aMysql = mydb.cursor()

def logincheck(e_username,e_password,_type):
    print("im here")
    _sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s AND password = %s"
    _val = (e_username,e_password)
    try:
        aMysql.execute(_sql,_val)
        result = aMysql.fetchall()
    except mysql.OperationalError:
        connect()
        aMysql.execute(_sql,_val)
        result = aMysql.fetchall()
    if len(result) >= 1:
        if result[0][0].lower() == e_username and result[0][1] == e_password:
            if _type == "main":
                logs.loginlog(e_username,result[0][2])
            return True,result[0][1],result[0][2]
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Problem is it just exit the application right after i clicked the login button, with no error. It prints `im here` fine but if i trying inserting print anywhere after that line in sql.py, it does not print just exited the app. Please advise. This code have no problem working on my tkinter app.

[image]

Comment: Suppose `connect()` or `aMysql.execute()` is failing, but not with an `mysql.OperationalError`? Add a catch-all `except` to write to a log if that happens. What happens if `len(result)` is zero?

Comment: if `len(result)` iz zero, it will returns `False` where it will trigger a messagebox to popup saying `invalid credential`. I've tried adding a catch-all `except`, and it printed it out, but im not sure what the error is. i tried it with no try-except, same problem arises, no error in output, it just exited the app.

Comment: So it appears your code did run into an untrapped exception. In the catch-all `except`, call `traceback.format_exc()` and send what it returns to a logfile.

Comment: nice that helps a lot! i've been stuck for 3 days on this. Turns out it was a `NoneType` error. and `aMysql` has no attribute 'execute` because i didnt call the required function at the start of the app. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are other problems with your code (some of them serious), for instance: 1. You shall never mix different UI toolkits (since you're porting to PyQt, use the [static functions of QMessageBox](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members)); 2. `Ui_login` has no `logindestroy` method; 3. as said in the warning you ignored and removed, you shall **never** edit a pyuic file, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); 4. it's normally better to use `isinstance` instead of comparing `type`.

Comment: 5. Make sure you run your code in a normal console/command-window (i.e. *not* an IDE) so you can see any python tracebacks or qt messages.

Comment: @musicamante yeah, about that, im porting my tkinter code to PyQt, so i havent get to that part since i was still figuring out said problem. `logindestroy` method is in my code, i just cut it out to shorten the code i post here since it is not related to the problem. all i did was adding the button connect to the method in pyuic code. thanks dude.

@ekhumoro i didn't know that. thanks dude

Comment: @blurryrox the fact is, without knowing the exact issue (which can generally be found by following the suggestion by ekhumoro), we can only guess: for all we know, you could've just mispelled the name of a variable or statement in that function. Always try to provide a [mre] we can work with, if you remove portions of code ensure that they are *not* part of the problem (otherwise the example would *not* be reproducible). Besides, using different toolkits can also be a source of problems, so you should also exclude that by *not* using tk while trying to figure out the cause of the problem.

Comment: @musicamante got it. i'll have that in mind. Thank you for the great advice.